# Having trouble tidying up data in R

Tags: r, dataset, large-data

I have a dataset that contains observed data on 8 brands of deodorant (data is fictional) across a few different stores. The data that is observed is:

- Week: week in which the observation took place
- Chain: the store in which the observation took place
- Brand: the brand of deodorant observed
- Sales: sales volume
- Price: price at which the supermarket bought the product
- Retail Price: price at which the brand is sold to the customer
- Display: a number proportional to the amount of display opportunities that the brand received at that time
- Feature: a number proportional to the amount of featured opportunities that the brand received at that time
- DisplayFeature: a number proportional to the amount of featured and display opportunities that the brand received at that time (when both features and display opportunities were present)

For me, the most logical way of representing this data would be to organize each variable listed above in a column where each row corresponds to an observation. However, the datafile that I got was presented as follows:

There is no variable column for the brand, instead all of the other variables are "spread out" over the brand, that is: there is a column called "DOVESales" where each element of this column is the amount of sales that the Dove deodorant had in this particular time point. There is another column called "DOVEPrice" where each element of this column is the price for the Dove deodorant in that week, etc...

So the first 13 columns of the first row in the raw datafile look like this:
[image: First observation, showing the first 13 columns]

whereas the first row in my dataframe should look like this:
[image]

I tried to use the tidyr gather() function to convert the wide data to long data and used the following code:

```
df <- df.raw %>% gather(Brand, Sales, 2:10) %>% 
                        gather(Brand, Price, 2:10) %>% 
                          gather(Brand, RPrice, 2:10) %>% 
                            gather(Brand, Display, 2:10) %>% 
                              gather(Brand, Feature, 2:10) %>%
                                gather(Brand, DisplayFeature, 2:10) %>%
   View()
```

But then my dataframe would contain over a billion rows and the file is too large to open. Does anyone know what would be the correct way to tidy up this kind of data?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you give us a sample of your data to make your job reproducible? It should be nice to provide the output of `dput(head(your_data,20))`, if 20 rows are ok for your question and you can publish them.

Comment: The `data.table` version of `melt()` is able to reshape multiple value columns from wide to long format. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] - Thank you.